# actionscript 3 export data to XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, export-to-excel

How do I export data from my SWF file to an XML file?

For example if there are 10 players (dyna blaster style game) and you want to store the scores over a longer period of time in a Excel file. You have to have the game create an XML file first, I figured that out myself. But how to export the data to an XML file first?

And also - is there a way to export the data from an swf file to mySQL on the server where my webSite is located ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly export to CSV (excel-ish fileformat)? http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/

Otherwise you have to create a `new XML()` and parse the object into it. The [AS3 templelib](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/) has a module to  load, parse, encoding all kinds of data, such as XML, JSON or images.
*See:* http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/data/readme.html

Comment: so are you saying that that CSV thingie is the best / simplest way possible to export my data from running swf file? is there not any better way? I'm asking because I'm not an AS3 pro, I'm still learning how to do stuff...